# How to store success value of ajax in variable by skipping html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how to store success value in variable by skipping html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button1").click(function(){
        var clicked1 =  $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "love.php",
            cache: true,
            type: "POST",
            data:{xyz:clicked1},
            success: function(data){
                var myvalue =   data;
                var msgdiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
                msgdiv.innerHtml = myvalue;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Question is not clear.

Comment: can you add some more data to question it not clear

Comment: all the success value from ajax goes in

Comment: You already store it in a variable (`myvalue`), and skipping (injecting it into your) html is just that: skip `msgdiv.innerHtml =  ...`. If this is not your question, then please elaborate on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you don't want to save the success value in HTML, but in JS variables, do you? Maybe it's obvious, but just try to use global variables, like:

```
var successVar;    
 $(document).ready(function () {
     ...
     success: function(data){
       successVar = data;
     }
 });
```

Or you can always use Storage objects where localStorage is for longer stored data, whereas sessionStorage is only for the current browser session:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("successKey", data)
window.localStorage.setItem("successKey", data)
```